# Принять данные из post запроса на странице php без перезагрузки

Tags: php, битрикс, post

вас!
Дело все происходит в cms битрикс.

На странице php вызываю компонент, тот возвращает таблицу. В этой таблице есть ссылка на сортировку позиций такого вида:

```
/module_tests_index.php&sort-field=XML_ID&sort-order=asc&by=XML_ID&order=desc
```

она ведёт на эту же страницу, но содержит нужные данные.
После перехода по ссылке происходит перезагрузка таблицы без перезагрузки страницы.

Задача глобальная - настроить сортировку в таблице.
Шаг - принять данные из запроса. Запустить функцию сортирующую список в таблице.

JS  я так понимаю не подходит. Что делать?

Comment: Непонятен вопрос. Если таблица уже перезагружается, то какие и зачем ещё нужно принимать данные?

Comment: да, хороший вопрос. Надо получается до перезагрузки таблицы подсунуть ей данные по новому запросу отсортированные. В принципе можно и потом ещё раз перезагрузить таблицу через js метод, но хочется ближе к нативности. Только битриксоиды не очень подсказывают новичкам...

Comment: Опять непонятно. В настоящий момент таблица уже перерисовывается без перезагрузки таблицы или нет? Она перерисовывается отсортированная как надо или нет? В общем, нативный способ - это включить режим AJAX в компоненте, и всё, - остальное сделает сам компонент. То есть сначала добиваетесь всего, чего вам нужно с перезагрузкой страницы, а потом включаете режим AJAX и получаете то же самое, но без перезагрузки.

Comment: То что у меня сейчас перезагружается или нет я готов всё это свернуть в угоду нативному решению битрикс. Сейчас у меня есть на страницу форма  и на этой же странице компонент таблицы без данных. Из запроса ajax  я получаю нужные данные но как их нативно засунуть в таблицу и чтобы таблица сразу работала с сортировкой не понятно.

Answer (score 0):

Итак, у вас есть страница, на странице есть компонент, компонент возвращает таблицу. В этой таблице есть ссылка на эту же страницу (важно!) с параметрами. При переходе по этой ссылке страница перерисовывается и на этой странице таблица уже отрисовывается отсортированной, верно? Добавьте в вызов компонента параметр 'AJAX_MODE' => 'Y', и компонент будет работать без перезагрузки.

Чтобы досконально разобраться с режимом AJAX в битрикс, советую изучить https://yunaliev.ru/file/bitrix_ajax_api.pdf